# How to show $A$ and $P^{-1}BP$ have same minimal polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ and $B$, be two $n\times n$ matrices such that $A=P^{-1}BP$
>   for some invertible matrix $P$. Show that both $A$ and $B$ have the
>   same minimal polynomial.

I'm not sure how to approach this. The only method I know to find minimal polynomial of a matrix is to estimate from its characteristic polynomial using the fact that characteristic polynomial and minimal polynomial must have same roots. Any hints/suggestions?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I've seen that answer you've linked. It seems to use way more machinery than I know. I've just taken a first course in LA

Comment: Well, since you have to prove this for *any* invertible matrix, you won't be able to calculate the specific polynomial.  You need to show that that $A$ and $P^{-1}AP$ satisfy the same polynomials.

Comment: @user296602 That answer talks about "characteristic polynomial", not minimal polynomial. I don't understand why people are closing this as duplicate.

Comment: Hint: $(P^{-1}AP)^2 = P^{-1}APP^{-1}AP = P^{-1}A^2P$

Comment: @saulspatz That makes sense. So I could just plug in $P^{-1}$ and $P$ at the front and end of the minimal polynomial, to express it in that form and show that if $A$ satisfies the minimal polynomial and so does $B$. BUT that doesn't prove that it is indeed the "minimal polynomial for $B$". B could satisfy equations other than the minimal polynomial, too.

Comment: For any polynomial $f$ we have $$f(A) = f(P^{-1}BP) = P^{-1}f(B)P$$
so $f(A) = 0$ if and only if $f(B) = 0$. Now it should be clear that $A$ and $B$ have the same minimal polynomial.

Comment: @mechanodroid Ah, we need to show it both ways I guess. $A$ satisfies the minimal polynomial of $B$ and $B$ satisfies the minimal polynomial of $A$, to make the proof complete. I get the idea though, thanks

Comment: @Blue The above shows that $A$ and $B$ satisfy the same set of polynomials. The monic polynomial of minimal degree in that set is the minimal polynomial for both $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Right, but now you prove it in the other direction.  In fact, you've already proved it, because $A = P(P^{-1}AP)P^{-1}.$

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks, that helped!